Low quality video in Eevee
I've been using the blender for a long time. I noticed the problem for the first time. Poor quality when rendering animation in Eevee. Using blender 3.6


The problem is that you're rendering straight to MP4 format, which is a lossy format. If quality is your main concern then rendering to individual frames as an EXR or PNG image sequence and then using an external encoder would be the best bet.

Thanks I'll try

As mentioned in the comment, the issue is with the file output settings.
But to be more exact, it's not the format that is an issue, it's the codec and its settings. MP4 supports a wide array of features, so you could have an old CD-era encoding, as much as you could have a lossless DNxHD for editing, or a very quality-vs-weight efficient VP9 or AV1 encoding for high quality streaming. But you set your render to be a DivX, which is an old DVD-era codec that will not go far in quality.
Video vs image output
If you ask most people, especially from the industry, encoding a video when rendering your 3D scene is the last thing anyone would want to do. For multiple reason:

Speed: you already need your resources to render, it's a waste of time and energy to encode a video on top of that
Safety: by the nature of resource-intensive tasks being at risk of crashing, doing multiple of them at once is riskier.
Reliability: if you crash, the whole render needs to be done from the beginning
Flexibility: unless you made a lossless (but heavy and slow) encoding, you need to re-render everything if there is a need to re-render even a single frame (if one frame rendered incorrectly, or you changed your mind about something, or...)
Post-render usability: unless you made a lossless encoding with high bit depth, you can't do much editing or color grading afterward, the lack of color depth will quickly show artifacts when bending colors, and the lack of full frame storage replaced by I/B/P frames makes editing imprecise.
Lightweight data: lossless videos are heavy and slow as hell, so nobody wants to use them in the first place
Quality: lossy videos are easily ugly due to data compression, and not always lighter than an image sequence.

On the other hand, outputting videos instead of image files can have some benefits:

Final result out of the box: if you don't need any form of editing, color grading or post-render tinkering, it can be interesting to output a video right there. But this usually comes only in scenarios where the render job is lightweight, typically animation previews or render tests.
Wide support: if using a set of standard encoding settings for steaming, you can expect to be able to send such a file to pretty much any software, website or system and expect it to work as is. However, you still could render as an image sequence first, and then encode that into a video. This way you get only the advantages of both at the cost of a bit of extra time.

For all these reasons, most people rarely use a video output when rendering, unless it's for a fast preview render.
People would most of the time prefer rendering into an image sequence. Because they avoid ALL the aforementioned issues.
Video output settings
If you want to encode a video, you could use some of the provided presets:

If your goal is video streaming (such as posting on YouTube, or social media), with no editing after rendering, using H264 in MP4 is the most widely supported and is set to give an image quality in the average of what you could get in most steaming platforms.
If you need to do any form of editing, then a good solution is to use the H264 in Matroska for scrubbing preset, and then switch the container back to MP4 which is more widely supported than Matroska. That way, you have the encoding settings suited for editing in a widely available container.

Image output
Most common image formats for sequence rendering:

EXR: the fastest to read and write, industry standard, supports high bit depth data, render passes (with the multilayer variant), very efficient lossless or lossy compression with very light file size and visually no loss even for editing. But it's AFAIK the only image format in Blender that doesn't write Blender's color management, so you will get a linear image that needs a base of color grading afterward. But may not be supported in softwares aimed at non-professionals only.
DPX next fastest, supports low and high bit depth, alpha, efficient file size vs quality compression, allows editing and color grading. A good alternative if you don't want to do base color grading and don't need render passes. But may not be supported in softwares aimed at non-professionals only.
Targa Raw, slower, heavier, but high bit and very wide support.
JPEG, faster than TGA Raw and lighter, but very dirty. Use only for previewing.

I would stay away from PNG for rendering a sequence, as it is by far the slowest format. Though if you render a still image, not an animation, it's totally viable. If you need to edit the render afterward, prefer using a 16bit depth PNG instead of the default 8.
Using an image sequence:
Most editing softwares (including Blender) can import image sequences, so you won't have issues with that. You can also use Blender's VSE as a tool to preview the image sequence. There are also dedicated softwares to read image sequences, such as DJV
